# Where can I find the Shield of Valor?

Tags: legend-of-grimrock

I completed the game with 5 of the 6 pieces of the valor set. I'd like to find the 6th piece for the *Knight in Shining Armor* achievement. It appears that I am missing the shield, but I don't know where to look. Where can I find it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a secret section called the "Fighter's Challenge".  The Shield of Valor is the reward.

Here's how to complete the Fighter's Challenge.

Hint 1:

> Go to level 6.  The challenge is completely contained on this level.

Hint 2:

> Get the **Sword of Nex**.  This is required to reach the challenge.

Hint 3:

> The **Sword of Nex** is in the Halls of Fire.  Get this from the room with the pits and Uggardians (fireball warriors).  You might have to equip it (not sure).

Final hint:

> 1. Find the secret entrance the opposite direction from the room with pits.  This secret entrance is still in the Halls of Fire.  There is a hidden switch at the dead-end hallway.
>  2. Go down the stairs.
>  3. Walk up to the gargoyle wall decoration (the demon face).

Short walkthrough of the challenge:

> You will be teleported to your doom, fighting bugs for the next ten years.
>
>  All of your party except your strongest fighter is likely going to die very quickly.
>
>  Try to get on a wall or corner so you're not surrounded on all four sides.  I recommend pre-prepared health and energy potions, bombs, lots of armor, as much evade as you can get, and a weapon/stats will ensure you hit every time.  Leave your inventory open with bombs and potions visible.
>
>  When you're done, grab the golden key off the floor, open the door, and claim your Shield of Valor.
>
>  If you are having trouble with it, come back after you have leveled a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Do the fighter's challenge: you get there from the separate stairs on level six.

Comment: Can you elaborate? What's the fighter's challenge?

Answer (score -3):

Shield is missing. Look here for exact guide: [Banshee](http://www.gamebanshee.com/legendofgrimrock/)

Comment: I appreciate the info that it's the shield I'm missing, but could you add more to your answer than just a link to the main page of the Banshee guide? That way no one else who is looking no one else has to reproduce the work of digging through that guide to find it.